# What is this form of javascript syntax? ( `this.prototype[name] = func;`)

Tags: javascript, prototype

So I was reading Douglas Crockford's article about [classical inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html), and saw the following code when he describes the sugar he wrote for his examples:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

Now, I've never see the syntax used on the second line, `this.prototype[name] = func;`.

How can you have an array that is used with `this.prototype`? What is this syntax? Where else can it be used?

Comment: Checkout MDN's documentation on [Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), especially [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). In short: `[]` aren't unique to `Array`s in JavaScript.

Comment: "array-access" notation can be used on any object just like dot notation.

Comment: Take that "classical inheritance" page with a large bag of salt. The last sentence on that page: _"I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake."_

Comment: @MattBall - You may have a point (?), but simply quoting some text in the abstract, not sure what the take-away is to be.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ah, thanks for clearing that up.